# Why is cygwin unable to find the Windows OpenSSH directory?

Tags: windows, cygwin, openssh

So I have installed OpenSSH for Windows 10 and have removed the one in cygwin. I am trying to get cygwin to use the Windows one instead but I am getting a strange error where cygwin cannot find the directory. I checked permissions and it all seems ok.

Here is what icacls says:

```
C:\Users\Steiny>icacls C:\Windows\System32
C:\Windows\System32 NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller:(F)
                    NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller:(CI)(IO)(F)
                    NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(M)
                    NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
                    BUILTIN\Administrators:(M)
                    BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
                    BUILTIN\Users:(RX)
                    BUILTIN\Users:(OI)(CI)(IO)(GR,GE)
                    CREATOR OWNER:(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
                    APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES:(RX)
                    APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES:(OI)(CI)(IO)(GR,GE)
                    APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\ALL RESTRICTED APPLICATION PACKAGES:(RX)
                    APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\ALL RESTRICTED APPLICATION PACKAGES:(OI)(CI)(IO)(GR,GE)

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files

C:\Users\Steiny>icacls C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH
C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller:(F)
                            NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller:(CI)(IO)(F)
                            NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(M)
                            NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
                            BUILTIN\Administrators:(M)
                            BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
                            BUILTIN\Users:(RX)
                            BUILTIN\Users:(OI)(CI)(IO)(GR,GE)
                            CREATOR OWNER:(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
                            APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES:(RX)
                            APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES:(OI)(CI)(IO)(GR,GE)
                            APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\ALL RESTRICTED APPLICATION PACKAGES:(RX)
                            APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\ALL RESTRICTED APPLICATION PACKAGES:(OI)(CI)(IO)(GR,GE)

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

Here is where cygwin complains:

```
{ ~ }  » ls -ld /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32
drwxr-xr-x 1 Steiny None 0 Feb 25 08:45 /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32
{ ~ }  » ls -ld /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH
ls: cannot access /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH: No such file or directory
```

Why can't cygwin find the `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH` directory?

Comment: Probably the bitness doesn't match between your cmd and cygwin bash shells.  Try `SysNative` instead of `System32`.  (If `cmd` is 64-bit and cygwin is 32)  Otherwise try `SysWOW64` (If using 32-bit `icacls` and cygwin is 64) Folder redirection is evil.

Comment: Oh I had no idea that the File System Redirector was a thing. That actually works. If you make it an answer I will accept it. Now the tricky part is that this directory is on the PATH. Maybe I just have to put both the System32 path and the SysNative path in there. Gross.

Comment: No, don't put `SysNative` into the 32-bit path, that will confuse everything.  A much better idea is to create a cygwin symlink to the file somewhere on the cygwin path (The command for that is `ln -s`)

Comment: @BenVoigt What about putting `C:\Windows\SysNative\OpenSSH` on the path? Is that going to cause any problems?

Comment: Does that directory contain any DLLs?  If so, it will cause problems.  I still suggest using symlinks to the applications you need.